# Listening to the Stream created from List in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

I've modified little bit example from tutorial https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/ by adding item after subscription:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  var data = new List<int>();
  var stream = new Stream.fromIterable(data);  // create the stream

  // subscribe to the streams events
  stream.listen((value) {       //
    print("Received: $value");  // onData handler
  });                           //
  data.add(1);
}
```

And after running this program I've got:

```
Uncaught Error: Concurrent modification during iteration: _GrowableList len:1.
Stack Trace: 
#0      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_collection-dev/iterable.dart:315)
#1      _IterablePendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:532)
#2      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:661)
#3      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:18)
#4      _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:11)
#5      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:151)
#6      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (timer_impl.dart:166)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:93)
```

Putting `data.add(1)` before adding listener works as expected.

I've checked [documentation about Stream](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-async.Stream@id_Stream-fromIterable) and didn't found what I am doing wrong. I was expecting that listener will be fired in best case and just not fired in worst case, but not exception.

Is it expected behavior? If yes, please describe why.

Comment: can you LOCK the "data" object before adding and RELEASE it after adding?

Comment: What do you mean by LOCK? As I know, Dart execution is single threaded and there is no need to do any thread synchronization. Can you point to manual about locking/unlocking?

Comment: sorry. yes, you cant :$. but the timer event will run asynchronous, and the .add is runnin immediately after the listen() call. so they will run concurrently (i.e. altering the array while the async call is using the iterator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception comes from you trying to modify the list while it is iterated over. This is unspecified behaviour in Dart (*), and the used implementation simply chose to throw an exception. While it is obfuscated by the asynchronous stuff happening in `Stream.fromIterable`, it basically is the same as if you tried to do this:

```dart
var data = [1,2,3];
for(var d in data) {
    print(d);
    data.add(d+10);
}
```

If you wrapped your `data.add` in another async call, for example with `Timer.run(() => data.add(2))`, it would "work". By that, I mean it wouldn't throw an exception.

`Received: 2` still would **not** be printed. The stream will only send the elements that where already in the list at the time `new Stream.fromIterable` was called. After that, the stream is closed (`onDone` will be called), and modifications to the original list will not be sent to your listener.

(*) Source: `iterator.dart` in SDK 1.1.3 -- "If the object iterated over is changed during the iteration, the behavior is unspecified." Why the text on api.dartlang.org is different is beyond me.

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comment: One way would be to use a `StreamController`.

```dart
// or new StreamController<int>.broadcast(), if you want to listen to the stream more than once
StreamController s = new StreamController<int>();
// produce periodic errors
new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
    s.isClosed ? t.cancel() : s.addError("I AM ERROR");
});
// add some elements before subscribing
s.add(6);
s.add(9);
// this will close the stream eventually
new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 20), () => s.close());
// start listening to the stream
s.stream.listen((v) => print(v), 
        onError: (err) => print("An error occured: $err"), 
        onDone: () => print("The stream was closed"));
// add another element before the next event loop iteration
Timer.run(() => s.add(4711));
// periodically add an element
new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) {
    s.isClosed ? t.cancel() : s.add(0);
});
// one more (will be sent before 4711)
s.add(4);
```

Comment: You are right, the iterator doesn't support async operation, therefore fromIterable can't be notified about later added elements.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative? I would like to have a stream, where I can 'emit' data so subscriber that can listen? I've found only abstract `CustomStream` from `dart:html`... This task sounds like something very easy and I've expected 'streams' should support this 'out-of-box'.

Comment: @ValentynShybanov Edited answer with alternative.

Comment: @MarioP great! That is exactly what I am looking for. `StreamController` should be definitely added to tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The List can't be modified while it is iterated over.
You need an iterable that doesn't have this limitation (e.g. custom implementation) for your example.

Comment: But isn't Dart execution sequential? There is no primitives for synchronization, only async module that used for asynchronous operations, not about parallelism. I would expect two possibilities: listener wouldn't be fired as it would be added on "next tick" or would be fired. But this behavior looks like something is happening in parallel and there is no control on it.

Comment: I guess stream.fromIterable() aquires an iterator from the list and the list throws if it is being modified while the iterator is not yet released. I have to take a closer look at how iterable is implemented, though.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason - during `fromIterable` it acquired iterator and on next tick it tried to move next over that iterator, but source list was modified before leaving context of `main`. Still I think that world 'concurrent' is not a best description of the error as there is no concurrent execution...